# inyectar código html con angular

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, component, innerhtml

Tengo un botón que cada vez que se pulsa inyecta un código HTML en un div contenedor. El codigo inyectado es el siguiente.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 mt-2 pr-0">
       <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
             <span class="input-group-text inputMini" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">IMEI</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control inputMini" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 mt-2 pr-0">
       <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
             span class="input-group-text inputMini" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">BUZÓN</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control inputMini" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-2 pr-0 d-flex-left-center">
        <button class="btn rounded-circle" (click)="removeDevice($event)>
          <em class="fa fa-times"></em>
        </button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Como se observa, estoy añadiendo un elemento que contiene una llamada a una función en ese código inyectado.

Los elementos me los pinta correctamente en pantalla pero al pulsar sobre el elemento que contiene la llamada a la función removeDevice(), nunca entra a esa llamada. ¿Alguien me puede decir porque motivo no entra? ¿Estoy inyectando el código html de forma correcta?

el codigo en el componente  que he creado para inyectar ese código

```
@ViewChild('addDevice', {static: false}) divDevice: ElementRef;

const div: HTMLDivElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
div.className = "col-md-12";

div.innerHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="col-5 mt-2 pr-0"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text inputMini" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">IMEI</span></div><input type="text" class="form-control inputMini" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"></div></div><div class="col-5 mt-2 pr-0"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text inputMini" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">BUZÓN</span></div><input type="text" class="form-control inputMini" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"></div></div><div class="col-2 pr-0 d-flex-left-center"><button class="btn rounded-circle" (click)="removeDevice($event)"><em class="fa fa-times"></em></button></div></div>';

this.renderer.appendChild(this.divDevice.nativeElement, div);
```

Gracias de antemano

Saludos

Comment: nose exactamente que es lo que quieres hacer. Pero tu código del `click` no funciona porque lo estas inyectando dinamicamente. Y le estas poniendo la directiva `(click)` que es algo propio de angular y no de js. Angular previamente compila todas estas directivas a js que entiende el navegador. Es por eso que no te funciona. Si quieres añadir un event handler lo puedes hacer con `addEventListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de que creas el elemento debes agregar el `listen` con `renderer2` de esta manera:

```js
 this.eventoClick = this.renderer.listen(
      document.getElementById("AGREGAR-EVENTO"),
      "click",
      evt => {
        this.removeDevice(evt);
      }
    );
```

Yo estoy agregando `id='AGREGEGAR-EVENTO'` a tu botón dentro del string que usas para generar el `HTML`

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cw5eyq)